# Open file in new window from macvim

Tags: vim, macvim

In MacVim, I can use `:e file` to open a file in a new buffer or `:tabe file` to open a file new a new tab. How can I open a file in a new window?

I would be happy with `⌘+N` followed by `:e file`, but that doesn't seem to work either... The working directory on the new window defaults to `~/`

Comment: Might be through external shell command? `! vim file.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

To which terminology are you referring when you say "window"?

In vim terminology (`:h window`), it's simply done with `:split` or `:vsplit` => `:sp file`.